# Upload as Teaser Background

Tags: views, entities, theming, nodes

I have created a views page which displays teasers of specific content type.

When creating content I am also uploading an image which we want to display on the background of the relevant teaser.

So every teaser has its image on the background.

Looking forward for professional guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Background Images Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter) module, hopefully it will fulfill your requirement.

> Background Images Formatter module provides an image formatter who allows you to set an image
>   in background of a div. The images are from a field of an entity and
>   not from a configuration page or sth else, so it's very easy to setup
>   and manage.

Change selector value to whatever you want in manage display section (explained in attached screen shot)

[image]

Comment: Please always try to make answer better so that it will be useful in future.. Above module has a name instead of using simply "this". Please try to be more descriptive instead of simply copy pasting from Module page!!

Comment: Hi Astha thanks for the reference module, I have installed that module and from manage display settings I have selected that image formater as setting but it is changing the complete background image of the page instead of changing the teasers background. Can you please guide me how to use this module in my use case ?? Thanks again

Comment: @Fahad I have attached screen shot to answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Asthachauhan Thanks for screenshot, I have now defined the required CSS selector but this time it is showing same image to all the teasers background

Comment: @Fahad You have to define a unique class or id for your teaser field.See its field settings if you can give a different class name or do it by jQuery.

Comment: Hello, I'm the maker of the module, if you need any help, just ask.